# How would I implement parsing using operator precedence?

Tags: parsing, operator-precedence

I want to implement parsing using operator precedence. I have implemented +, -, *, and /.  How would I implement rest with out using any grammar? This is a college project and yacc or bison are not allowed.

Comment: You might find this interesting/useful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/04/no-backtracking-part-one.aspx

Comment: @Lazarus: ["The homework tag...is now discouraged,"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10812) but, @sanjoy, please (as always) follow [general guidelines](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints): state any special restrictions, show what you've tried so far, and ask about what specifically is confusing you.

Comment: @Roger Pate: of course it is now, after all that would discourage people from posting their homework questions verbatim and actually having to learn. And I thought political correctness in the workplace had passed the point of ridiculousness.

Comment: @Lazarus: Verbatim assignments will be posted with or without the [homework] tag; questions that show no effort and are thus too vague to reasonably answer should be downvoted and closed, with instructions on how to better ask questions (I've done all three here).  The use of [homework] to somehow indicate other answerers should respond in a particular way is confusing and conflicting, but, more importantly, it doesn't help the OP learn and, I believe, ends up being actively harmful towards that goal: saying it's okay to post a vague question with no effort as long as a specific tag is used.

Comment: How does your grammar look like? It is a full-blown language, or just some math equation?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a recursive descent parser (because that's the only parser that can easily be written by hand). See Wikipedia for details, it's pretty easy.

So, to get operator precedence right you can do something like this:

```
term = number
unary = ('-' | '+')* term
multiplication = unary ('*' | '/' unary)*
addition = multiplication ('+' | '-' multiplication)*
expression = addition
```

Where 'expression' is your starting rule.

Comment: any grammar can be implemented by operator precedence parsing?

Comment: no, a grammar can be implemented by any suitable parsing mechanism (recursive descent is one method). operator precedence is simply a feature of a grammar and has nothing to do with the chosen parsing method.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not allowed to use a parser generator, I would recommend reading about the [Recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser)
. 
A very good introduction is included in the [Dragon Book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools)

Answer (score -1):

If you need a quick fix:

http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/index.php?title=Recursive_descent_parsing

more extensive reading:

[Basic Compiler Design](http://www.diku.dk/hjemmesider/ansatte/torbenm/Basics/basics_lulu2.pdf)

GLHF!